# Multiple dropdown box variables

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am having some difficulty getting my php form to function. I am trying to use multiple dropdown boxes that all reference a database and fill themselves from the respective values.

As you can see in my code below, I am trying to create a query using the results from the box "email" and "type". Can anyone help?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
    $host = "****";
    $dbname = "****";
    $username = "****";
    $password = "****";

@   $connection = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
@   mysql_select_db($dbname,$connection);

    if (!$connection) {
    die('=( Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo '<b>Connected successfully to $dbname</b>';
    mysql_close($connection);

    /*
    Check to see if connection was successful
    */



?>

    <form name="survey" method="post" action="scripts/report_script.php" onSubmit="">

        Email:

        <select name="email">
<!-- Begin email selection -->
            <?php 
                mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
                mysql_select_db($dbname);
                $email_query = "SELECT sgl_userID,sgl_user_email FROM tbl_sgl_user";
                $email_result = mysql_query($email_query);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($email_result)){

                    echo '<option value="'.$row['sgl_userID'].'">'.$row['sgl_user_email'].'</option>';
                }

            ?>
        </select>
<!-- End email selection -->
<!--Start Survey Type selection-->
            <select name="type">
                <option value="government">Government</option>
                <option value="sport">Sport</option>
                <option value="school">School</option>
            </select>
<!--End Survey Type selection-->
<!--Start Date selection-->
            <select name="date">
                <?php
                    mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
                    mysql_select_db($dbname);
                    $date_query = "SELECT survey_date FROM tbl_survey WHERE survey_name='$type' AND sgl_userID='$email'";
                    $date_result = mysql_query($date_query);
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($date_result)){
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['survey_date'].'">'.$row['survey_date'].'</option>';
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
<!--End Date selection-->
        <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So how do you except to use $email and $type to make your last query if your user haven't submitted any data ? You need to either change your form of to use AJAX to submit the first 2 fields and get the results to populate your 3 one.

Comment: Thanks @Prix. Have you got any tips as to where I can find into on this? Struggling a little.

Comment: A very simple way for you would be to make your first form with email and type, and submit it to your second form, then you will have email and type to use on your query to make your 2nd form.

Comment: Hmmm. So you think that perhaps a second page would be needed?

Comment: Yes and no, in your case since you are begging with php and MySQL that's what I would recommend you, so you can understand how it works. However it's also possible to do with 1 form using AJAX but its not so simple for some one just starting out.